# How to install holiday api from github

Tags: php

How to install holiday api from github : 
https://github.com/joshtronic/holidayapi.com

My current system setup is : 
Win 7
wamp2.2
php5.3

Error displayed :

> Warning: require_once(pickles.php) [function.require-once]: failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   D:\wamp\www\holidayapi\public\index.php on line 5
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required 'pickles.php'
>   (include_path='.;D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\pear;/usr/share/pickles-dev/src')
>   in D:\wamp\www\holidayapi\public\index.php on line 5

Answer (score 0):

It's expecting to find a library called "pickles" in /usr/share/pickles-dev

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/usr/share/pickles-dev/src');

require_once 'pickles.php';
```

Comment: yah, where can I get it?

Comment: Your best bet is to ask the people behind this API project to document its dependencies. But it's most likely https://github.com/joshtronic/pickles a PHP MVC framework

Comment: Thanks Dave, I've have tried that also but pickles.php is not included in that source.

Comment: Holy crap, this got asked on my birthday! Anyway, I'm the dev behind HolidayAPI.com and at the time it did rely on `pickles`. The whole thing has since been reworked to no longer have that dependency and should a ton easier to get up and running locally now by way of `gulp`. Happy hacking!